# Why Linux doesn't get booted automatically only If I changed the BOOT.bin not the zImage, while in the first case it gets automatically booted

Tags: embedded, xilinx, linux, bootloader

I have zynq board ( not the zedboard), it doesn't have all the peripherals of zedboard.
I am facing some problem while booting the linux on zynq with my new BOOT.bin.

When I used to put the sdcard in the zynq board which had three file BOOT, devicetree, zImage. Here BOOT is the old file which was already created by someone.
The linux automatically boots up and lots of printing happens on screen probably loading all linux drivers etc. 
and I get a 
"root@mcontroller" prompt. like this:
 [image]

But Now I have made a new BOOT file from xilinx sdk.
Now I put three files in the sd card. BOOT , devicetree and zImage. 
plugin the card in the zynboard.

I get 
"Zynq-uboot>" prompt

[image]

Okay I captured the above image when i was using windows but I get the same prompt while using ubuntu also.

I do not understand the difference between the root@mcontroller and zynq-uboot prompt?
Why I am not getting the root@mcontroller when I change the BOOT bin file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zynq-uboot>` prompt is the uBoot command interpreter. `root@mcontroller#` is a Linux shell prompt. So in the first capture you're up and running in a Linux environment. In the second capture you're still in the bootloader. You'll need to look at the uBoot commands to figure out how to start running the Linux image.

Comment: I changed the Question, Can you help me there?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used uBoot but I'll give it a shot. From the screen capture it looks like you have several boot scripts defined in the environment so you probably just need to execute the right one. Since you mentioned an SD card, try loading it with `nmc_loadbit_fat` and then `bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000`. If you can, check the commands that the original BOOT image contained. That should give you a better feel for how to proceed.

Comment: I am really sorry but how to load it with nmc_loadbit_fat?, and I don't know that how can I check the commands that the original BOOT image contained.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I was just looking at the screen capture of the bootloader environment and it looked like there were some scripts available. Your best bet is looking at the original setup that worked and see what commands are executed. There needs to be some sort of command to load an image into memory and then execute it.

Comment: I got it resolved the problem was that I was using the wrong u-boot.elf file for the generation of BOOT.bin. I used the correct u-bbot.elf and generated the BOOT.bin and just replace the BOOT.bin with new BOOT.bin and when I plugged in the sd card in board I got the linux and root@mcontroller prompt.                                                          But now my HDMI port is not working does that mean that the problem is with my hardware design (xilinx EDK)which I used for new BOOT.bin generation?